# How do I update kotlin-js-library to 1.1.3 like the kotlin-gradle-plugin has been?

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-2, build.gradle, kotlin

If you look at:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/

the current version is 1.1.3 but:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-js-library/

is stuck back at 1.0.7. How can I trigger this to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [kotlin dev repository](https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/) has all what you want. just add the repository in `build.gradle` as below:

```
buildscript{
  repositories{
     maven{ url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/" }
  }
}

repositories{
   maven{ url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/" }
}
```

and the `kotlin-js-library` at here: https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-js-library/

Comment: got me to next step but still this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837218/what-is-correct-version-match-between-kotlin-gradle-plugin-and-kotlin-js-library