# What is correct version match between kotlin-gradle-plugin and kotlin-js-library?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, kotlin

I have:

```
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
   ext.kotlin_js_version = '1.1-M04'

   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     maven{ url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/" }
   }

   dependencies {
     classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
   }
```

then in another build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-js-library:$kotlin_js_version"
}
```

But I always get:

> org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-js-library/1.1-M04/ef6b315dbb89927eb72fbce262ba3a74dc1ebcb5/kotlin-js-library-1.1-M04.jar'
>   was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary
>   version of its metadata is 6.0.0, expected version is 1.0.1

I want the latest of both. I think? Or does one lag behind the other?

Comment: Hi, I'm about to go sleeping.the version number should the same. there is an exmaple https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/v1.1.3/libraries/examples/kotlin-js-library-example

Comment: `kotlin-js-library` was renamed to `kotlin-stdlib-js`. Use the latter artifact name.

Comment: ah ha! that's the ticket!

Answer (score 0):

you can find the latest release versions here:
https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.jetbrains.kotlin%3Akotlin-stdlib

right now it is on: 1.1.3-2